# angular ui select prevent model removing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to prevent an item to be removed in case if Backspace or delete was pressed. The thing is that user can actually remove current element in ui-select if ui-select got focus and user pressed backspace or delete button. I would like to prevent this scenario. Does any one know how to do this?

Seems like the lement itself can not do it out of the box.

Thanks.

**UPD**

Unfortunately I can't post any code because there is nothing spetial in this case. 
If some one want to try this behavious by exmple go  [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-basic.html)
, select some thing in *select 2 theme* and press backspace or delete.

Comment: What have you go so far, code snippets would be useful.

Comment: there is no meaning in code because there is nothing specific about this case. It's not a special case

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/926 might help you